# Using jquery $.ajax to PHP post GET values

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP script which i want to pass a value in. So `example.com/test.php?command=apple`. If that's entered then do its code. That all works grand in the server side but how do i accomplish this using an ajax call?

My code:

PHP:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['command']=='apples')
{
    //do code
    echo "hello";
}       
?>
```

Jquery:

```
$.ajax({
    url : '../command/test.php?command=apples'
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log("result: " + data);
});
```

Comment: Do you get any error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the data into a data section, I think that will solve your problem.

```
$.ajax({
    url : '../command/test.php',
    data: {command: "apples",login: "succes"}
}).done(function(data) {
    console.log("result: " + data);
});
```

Also, you can see what you get as a response, open developer tools and you can see under `network` your request appearing when made, click on that and you can see the response.

Comment: How do i pass multiple commands in? So: `$_GET['command']=='apples'` and `$_GET['login']=='success'`?

Comment: Like any `array`, just a `,` and then your next value. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I was doing exactly what you did but no luck. Copied yours and worked ._. Must of been asleep last night trying haha. Thanks a mill!!

Answer (score 3):

The Snippet below is Pretty straight-forward and self-explanatory... however should you have any questions, don't hesitate to use the comments functionality below this Post.... ;-)

**JQUERY: AJAX**....

```
        var request = $.ajax({
            url         : "../command/test.php",
            data        : {"command": "apples"},
            dataType    : "json",
            type        : "POST"
        });

        request.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            if(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });

        request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });
```

**PHP**....

```
<?php
    $response   = array();
    $command    = isset($_POST['command']) ? 
                  htmlspecialchars(trim($_POST['command'])) :
                  null;
    if($command){
        // BUILD UP YOUR RESPONSE HERE
        $response['command']  = $command;
        // ADD SOME ARBITRARY DATA - JUST FOR FUN
        $response['name']     = "Albert";
        $response['lastName'] = "Einstein";
     }

     die( json_encode($response) );
```

Answer (score 2):

You can send the value in a `POST` request to the `php` page and get the returned value from there all using `$.ajax`

for example we will calculate 2 numbers and return the sum via `ajax`

#### Example Code

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/path/to/page.php",
   type: "POST",
   data: {number_1: 10, number_2: 5},
   success: function(response){
      // alert $result from the php page which is called response here.
      alert(response);
   }
});
```

#### Php page

```
// checking if data exists
if ($_POST['variable_1'] != null && $_POST['variable_2'] != null ){
    $variable_1 = $_POST['variable_1'];
    $variable_2 = $_POST['variable_2'];
    $result = $variable_1 + $variable_2;
}else{
    // either of the values doesn't exist
    $result = "No Data Was Sent !";
}
// returning $result which is either 15 or " no data was sent "
echo $result;
```

This will return `15`. Hope this makes sense now.

Comment: This makes some sense to me but cant seem to get it going. Could you put an if statement into the php page in your answer? Or explain more? Thanks!

Comment: You can do whatever you want in the php. I will edit my answer to add a real life situation.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: "../command/test.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: ({command: 'apples'}),
            success: function(data)
            {
                console.log("result: " + data);                           
            }
        });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to post. You can use the url args or pass a data object.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "../command/test.php",
    data: {
        command: "apples"
    }
})
```